# sub content with full url?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When you browse facebook or youtube, you will notice that when you click on a link, it seems like the page did not full reload/refresh to the new page. The header or sidebar is there. But the URL show on browser address bar seems like a direct path to that page. On youtube, you are able to see the red loading bar at the very top of the page when loading a new page.

I have tried to do ajax page before and the URL will look something like this www.mydomain.com/#/content/subcontent/. So, how can I do one like facebook or youtube? Is it using HTML5 or anything? Any suggestion how to do it?

Thanks. Hope you can understand what I am trying to explain here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What these sites use is a HTML5 api called [History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) which lets you update the current page URL and site contents without doing a full redirect. I encorage you to read this article http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html and see this polyfill https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/ for manipulating the URI while loading other page segments.